# Get resources from another apk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, package-managers, getresource

I have been struggling with this issue all day and have had no success. I am basically trying to get an image resource from another apk.

So if com.example.app has an image called image1.png in the res folder, i want com.example2.app to be able to gain access to that resource and place it in an imageview.

I know you have to use PackageManager.getResourcesForApplication, but i have still been unsuccessful in getting the actual resource.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
final String packName = "com.example2.app";
    String mDrawableName = "app_icon";

    try {
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        Resources mApk1Resources = manager.getResourcesForApplication(packName);

        int mDrawableResID = mApk1Resources.getIdentifier(mDrawableName, "drawable",packName);

        Drawable myDrawable = mApk1Resources.getDrawable( mDrawableResID );

        if( myDrawable != null )
            TEST.setBackgroundDrawable(myDrawable );

    }
    catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

Check here for more explanation form other question! [Share raw resource between apk's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201776/share-raw-resource-between-apks)

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
final String packName = "com.example.app ";
Resources resources;
try {
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    resources = manager.getResourcesForApplication(packName);

    int resID = resources.getIdentifier("image1", "drawable", packName);
    Log.d(TAG, "resID = " + resID);
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(resID);
    Log.d(TAG, "resID = " + resID);
}
catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: When i tried this out, it was pulling images from my own app :-/. Evert time i ran it, it would go to the next image in the drawable folder.

Comment: yes i am. What it is doing is showing the drawable from my app and not the other app. So if i choose the 6th image down in the list of drawables in the chosen package, it will show the 6th image down in my drawables list instead. Am i just trying to show it in a imageview wrong? Would this work... TEST.setImageDrawable(image);

Comment: yes because it may be possible you have images in your drawable with same recourse id's

Comment: That makes sense. I understand it now, but i am now confused about decoding the image to a bitmap. Would i use decodeResource?

Comment: try as splashImageView.setImageResource(resources.getDrawable(resources.getIdentifier("image1", "drawable", packName)));

Comment: Nope, threw an FC saying no resource was found    (E/AndroidRuntime(31211): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0)

Comment: Change the resource object in line 9. It should be resources.getDrawable(resID).