# Where shoud I put keys/passwords in a safe way?

Tags: android, security

My app requires some keys. One for the google maps api and one for my own API. Where is a safe place to put those? I was thinking about putting them in a xml or in the manifest, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288147/get-resources-from-another-apk) says one is able to read an others resources.

Putting keys in a java file does not seem safe to me because they [can be decompiled.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files)

Where is a safe place to put my keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can hash them with some algorithm. And after obfuscate the code, it will be difficult to reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use NDK to hide your keys. For example you just put your keys to native code and then build *.so library. In this way you could get your keys throught JNI. But of course this is not a "silver bullet" and lurcher can decompile library(with troubles for sure) or link it to his project and then try to get keys. + obfuscate your code.